# Sidebar tracking toolbar items in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nstoolbar

Is there an official way to achieve an equivalent of an [NSTrackingSeparatorToolbarItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstrackingseparatortoolbaritem) **consistently** in SwiftUI yet?

I'm making an app that has 2 possible toolbar states, both have a "toggle sidebar" button I'd like to be in the actual sidebar, kinda like Xcode. I'm using a `NavigaionView` and I'm adding the sidebar button as follows:

```swift
NavigationView {
  List(selection: $selection) {
    ForEach(app.menuItems) { menuItem in
      Section(header: MenuSectionHeader(menuItem.name)) {
        OutlineGroup(menuItem.children ?? [SidebarItem](), children: \.children) { child in
          Label(child.name, systemImage: child.icon)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  .toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
      Button(action: toggleSidebar) {
        Icon(icon: "sidebar.left", .textDim)
      }
    }
  }

  DetailsView()
    .toolbar {
      // ...rest of the toolbar...
    }
}
```

And it works in one of the 2 states:

[image: expanded sidebar]

[image: collapsed sidebar]

But in the other state, the `.automatic` placement pushed it next to the center area:

[image: wrong placement]

There's nothing in the official [ToolbarItemPlacement docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toolbaritemplacement) that suggests it's possible to force a `ToolbarItem` to be in the sidebar, but given that automatic placement pushes it there *sometimes*, maybe there's something I'm missing.

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Did you try other placements, explicit, like .navigation or .navigationBarLeading, etc.?

Comment: @Asperi yep, I tried all the ones available on macOS (i.e. .navigationBarLeading is iOS-only), none of them do the trick. Some even just hide the item from the toolbar altogether

Comment: Side note, I'm trying out the new NavigationSplitView coming in Ventura and it has a toggle sidebar button inserted into the `.navigation` section by default. I'm wondering if there's a way to style that or move it to a different spot, can't see anything in the docs

Comment: Any new findings on NavigationSplitView?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put toolbar items inside the sidebar, attach toolbar modifier to List with SidebarStyle

```
List {
    Text("foo")
    Text("bar")
}
.listStyle(.sidebar)
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItemGroup {
        Button(action: {}, label: {
            Image(systemName: "sidebar.left")
        })
        Spacer()
        Button(action: {}, label: {
            Image(systemName: "play.fill")
        })
        Button(action: {}, label: {
            Image(systemName: "stop.fill")
        })
    }
}
```